# Can't delete a deployed printer from users computers

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, shared-printers

I am facing some weird issues when trying to remove a printer from the users machines on my domain  that was deployed with Group policy. When I try to remove it I get  **"access deny"** message **even tho I login as admin**. The policy is targeting computers only. How can I accomplish this without going back to the policy and filtering users? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the clients Windows 7 or 10?

Comment: Windows 7 and XP PCs.

Comment: Are the printers the defaults for the machines having problems? and are there any documents pending/printing when you try and delete? I've seen this with Win 10 but never got to the bottom of it.

Comment: No pending dcomments. I'm going to try and deploy it to users instead and see if i get a different result-. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Stop / Cancel any pending print tasks for the printer
Restart the print spooler service from the workstation and then try to remove it

Comment: There are no pending documents, however I am still unable to remove it.

Comment: were you able to restart the print spooler service on the workstation?

Comment: @Levis If you had restarted the spooler service, you can try to remove the printer from the print management console in Administrative tools.
Also, if this is happening with a network printer, try this script
[link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-remove-all-network-d3979e18). Please note that the script will remove all network printers. You can add them back